# Remove dots for chapters in ToC with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have seen similar posts but none seem to work. I simply need to remove the dots in the ToC between the chapter titles and the page numbers. I think the page numbers should line up (as if there were dots). This is using the memoir class. Here is my ToC info:

```
%%%% Do the ToC
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage\pagestyle{toc}\oldtoc}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand*{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
  \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
%\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{CHAPTER~}
%%% no extra space before the entry
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
%% no extra 'chapter' space in LoF/LoT
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{}
```

I tried everything that was suggested. Nothing seemed to make any difference. I am stuck with this format. Any suggestions would be greately appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You could just specify `\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\hfill}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\chapter{Second​​​ ​​​chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\chapter{Last chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

​\end{document}
```

If you're interested in removing the section dots, include

```
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionleader}{\hfill}
```

as well. The dots are referred to as "leaders", hence the command `\cft...leader`.

I've removed all the other formatting-related stuff that doesn't pertain to the problem (like page style headings and `\tableofcontents` redefinition, for example).

Comment: I will give this a try this evening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. However, try to remove (!) the following line in your code:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
```

Here's a MWE that shows the effect:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% \renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will give this a try this evening. Thanks!