# Yet another leader dot question and related for TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I asked a question yesterday. Thanks for the help. It turns out I only need to remove the leader dots AND the page number associated with "CHAPTER". This is using the `memoir` class and also uses a `.sty` file. I know this is not a minimal working example, but I don't know which line(s) of code are the problem. I have messed with them all...

Here is the main file

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pw1} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}
```

Here is relevant stuff  in the `pw1.sty` file

```
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage\pagestyle{toc}}\oldtoc}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand*{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
    \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
 \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
    {\cftdotsep} 
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
```

This is what I get:

> CHAPTER...............................................1

One other problem I am having is that the Chapter on page2
of the TOC is not all caps and needs to be. This one should  be simple, but...

> Chapter

Comment: Hi, are you the same person which posted this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33673/memoir-class-toc-question. If so, please tell us then we will merge the accounts. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Based on the comment to @ egreg's answer, I would say yes, but I guess it's best to make sure from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the chapter page numbers, then

```
\renewcommand\cftchapterformatpnum[1]{}
```

is what's needed. To get automatically uppercased titles, I found out this hack:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@chapapp
  {\hskip-\memRTLleftskip}
  {\hskip-\memRTLleftskip\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I have one (I wish) remaining problem right now that I am struggling with that I have been working on all day. Every page in my document has a 1" top margin EXCEPT the toc, lot and lof. These are all less than 1". I have tried everything I can find. Nothing seem to budge it such /vspace etc. This is memoir class. Please see my earlier post  or I can add example. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @brucebond007 Without a "real" example it's difficult to say; but I'd blame the pagestyle you're defining for them.