# Removing leader and page number from added line in ToC (memoir class)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

My question is very similar to this, but a little more complicated - [Yet another leader dot question and related for TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33763/yet-another-leader-dot-question-and-related-for-toc)

I am trying to format my ToC using the memoir class. I want my ToC to look like this..

```
           TABLE OF CONTENTS
                               Page
LIST OF TABLES ................. i 
LIST OF FIGURES ................ ii
CHAPTER
1 First chapter ................ 1
  subheading ................... 2
2 Second chapter ............... 3
```

Using the pwasu style file and memoir provided commands within, I have been able to make my ToC formatted to look like this...

```
           TABLE OF CONTENTS
                               Page
LIST OF TABLES ................. i 
LIST OF FIGURES ................ ii
CHAPTER ........................ 1
1 First chapter ................ 1
  subheading ................... 2
2 Second chapter ............... 3
```

Here is my current code...

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pwasu}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Here is my best representation of minimal code from pwasu

```
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage\pagestyle{toc}\oldtoc}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand*{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
  \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep} %%%% 
%\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{CHAPTER~}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{}
```

I want to get rid of the leaders and page number from the added content line, CHAPTER, as it is only there to signify the chapter numbers of subsequent chapters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular, either provide the `pwasu` package or merge the relevant part with your *current code*. When I tried to do that, `\undefinedpagestyle` was reported as `Undefined control sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

To add the word "CHAPTER", you can use the `\cftaddtitleline` command; its syntax is

```
\cftaddtitleline{ext}{kind}{title}{page}
```

so with an empty fourth argument you suppress the page number.

A quick (somehow hackish way) to remove the leaders (dots) for this particular entry is to introduce a local change with `\cftlocalchange` and then restore the original settings using again this command. An example illustrating this approach; probably the first argument (`309pt`) for `\cftlocalchange` will have to be slightly changed depending on the actual settings introduced by the file `pwasu.sty` (which is not available on CTAN):

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
  \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep} %%%% 
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{CHAPTER~}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\cftlocalchange{toc}{309pt}{0cm}% change settings to suppress dots
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}{}% add word "CHAPTER"
\cftlocalchange{toc}{1.55em}{2.55em}% restore original settings
\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]